# How to randomize related products in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I have the standard Shopify theme Minimal. Products are assigned to Collections.

Related Items on each product just show the first 4 items it finds in the related Collections. As there are many items in each collection, a lot of the time there related items are completely the same on 100s of products.

How do I edit the code to randomize the results on Related Products?

Comment: Actually it is not a good idea to show related products just based on collection data.  You should use past order data, tags, collections and many other factors to select related products that your customers will be interested in. It is not possible (because of performance issues) to implement such advanced algorithms to select related products by just using liquid template engine. I developed Recomify Related Products App ( https://apps.shopify.com/recomify ) for Shopify to make all this work easy, fast and absolutely automatic.

Answer (score 8):

Steph's answer is better but there is also this non-javascript (and also not truly random, but I like it anyway) solution that hacks date:

```
{% assign relatedCollection = collections['related-products'] %}
{% assign index = 'now' | date: '%S' %}
{% assign index = index | times: relatedCollection.products.size %}
{% assign index = index | divided_by: 60 %}
{% for product in relatedCollection.products offset: index %}

  ...

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Any advice to have this work for products not contained in any collection ie. `if product.collections.size < 1` ?

Comment: All products belong to at least one collection

Comment: This is a great date hack - how would you adjust this (and where would you put it?) to apply this to any collection - i.e.  I have large collections and would like them to all be totally randomized.

Comment: I'd use the javascript solution provided by Steph

Comment: Late to the game on this one but... I wanted to avoid JS, so I modified this as it is "random" enough for me.  I noticed that generating the offset index it would "truncate" the complete result set when iterating.  To solve that just add a second loop after this to "catch up" the missing items: {% for product in relatedCollection.products limit: index %}...{% endfor %}

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this article on the Shopify wiki: [Recommend related products to your customers](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/recommend-related-products). The section "[Find a relevant Collection to recommend products](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/recommend-related-products#find-a-relevant-collection-to-recommend-products)" provides a jQuery script for randomizing the related products shown.

> You can output all products from the relevant collection and pick a limited number of products randomly using this jQuery plugin: https://github.com/carolineschnapp/jquery-pick/blob/master/jquery.pick.js

See also: [Feature multiple random products on your home page](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/customization/showcase-products/feature-multiple-random-products)

Comment: this answer should include whatever the link contained in case it goes down again. links as answers are not answers.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code for showing the related products using metafields -

```
 {% if product.metafields.related_metafield != blank %}
{% assign metafieldArr = product.metafields.related_metafield.sku | split : ',' %} {% for singleMeta in metafieldArr %} {% assign prod = all_products[singleMeta] %}
{{ prod.title | escape }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Check Example - https://stellacove.com/collections/boys

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code.

```
    {%- assign paginate_index = limit | plus: 0 -%}
    {% assign total_products = collection.products.size %}
    {% assign start_index = "now" | date: "%L" | modulo: total_products %}
    {% assign start_index1 = start_index | plus: 5 %}
    {% if start_index1 >total_products %}
      {% assign start_index = 1 %}
    {% endif %}
    {% assign products_shown = 0 %}

    {% for product in collection.products %}
        {% if forloop.index0 >= start_index %}
          <!-- product display code -->
          {% assign products_shown = products_shown | plus: 1 %}
          {% if products_shown >= paginate_index %}{% break %}{% endif %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**