# How to randomize featured collection in Shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I'd like to randomize the order products in the featured collections in Dawn Shopify theme. I saw there is a similar solution on stakoverflow for related products: [How to randomize related products in Shopify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274489/how-to-randomize-related-products-in-shopify)

You know if is possible to fit the solution on my problem? Can you help me with the code?

I suppose this is the code to fitting (but I'm not sure):

```
        {%- for product in section.settings.collection.products limit: section.settings.products_to_show -%}
      <li id="Slide-{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.index }}" class="grid__item{% if show_mobile_slider or show_desktop_slider %} slider__slide{% endif %}">
        {% render 'card-product',
          card_product: product,
          media_aspect_ratio: section.settings.image_ratio,
          show_secondary_image: section.settings.show_secondary_image,
          show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor,
          show_rating: section.settings.show_rating,
          show_quick_add: section.settings.enable_quick_add,
          section_id: section.id
        %}
      </li>
    {%- else -%}
      {%- for i in (1..4) -%}
        <li class="grid__item">
          {% render 'card-product', show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor %}
        </li>
      {%- endfor -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
```

Comment: long shot but did you end up figuring it out? Im looking to do this with js too but can't come across any answer. im using the same theme as you what .liquid file should I mess with?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
{%- assign paginate_index = limit | plus: 0 -%}
    {% assign total_products = collection.products.size %}
    {% assign start_index = "now" | date: "%L" | modulo: total_products %}
    {% assign start_index1 = start_index | plus: 5 %}
    {% if start_index1 >total_products %}
      {% assign start_index = 1 %}
    {% endif %}
    {% assign products_shown = 0 %}

    {% for product in collection.products %}
        {% if forloop.index0 >= start_index %}
          <!-- product display code -->
          {% assign products_shown = products_shown | plus: 1 %}
          {% if products_shown >= paginate_index %}{% break %}{% endif %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```